# Best way to test in python if a py4j JVM is running?

Tags: java, python, py4j

What is a good way to test (in a python script) if a JVM running py4j is listening to the chosen (perhaps default) socket? Something like an intelligent `ping`?

I can try to access methods or objects from my Java class and catch the resulting `socket.error` exception, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Creating a python `JavaGateway` instance without any JVM to talk to doesn't raise an exception. I might have missed something, but I didn't find anything in [the docs](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/contents.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Py4J does not have a health check, ping, or version command, so the only three options to test if Py4J is listening are:

1. Try to connect to the socket. This method is not perfect because another server program might be listening to the default port.
2. Try to eagerly load the JavaGateway (will be available in the 0.8 version. It is now only available in the master branch on github):

   ```
   from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, Py4JNetworkError
   try:
       java_gateway = JavaGateway(eager_load=True)    
       print("JVM accepting connection")
   except Py4JNetworkError:
       print("No JVM listening")
   except Exception:
       print("Another type of problem... maybe with the JVM")
   ```
3. In Py4J 0.7, try to call a basic System method:

   ```
   from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, Py4JNetworkError

   java_gateway = JavaGateway()    
   try:
       java_gateway.jvm.System.getProperty("java.runtime.name")
       print("JVM accepting connection")
   except Py4JNetworkError:
       print("No JVM listening")
   except Exception:
       print("Another type of problem... maybe with the JVM")
   ```

[Feature requests](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j) are welcomed!

Comment: if the result of that compilation is "No JVM listening" what should we do ?

Comment: It probably means that the GatewayServer in the JVM has not started. You could use the launch_gateway function to launch a GatewayServer/JVM from Python.

Comment: is  there still no other solution? don't know if i have too much overhead but i have a java application which needs to call a python method which uses a python library. and i tested it with the listener example - changed some code. but now either i run the gateway the whole time and hole the reference forever on both sides or start the python script every time new when i need to call it - here maybe i start the same python script a lot of times? maybe there is a simple solution which i just dont get. using CallbackServerParameters and here eager is true